# How to search in database all Status is 0 or 1?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to search teachers name in the database either the status is 0 or 1? I dont know if this is correct **"Status"<=1**

```
SELECT * FROM "Teachers" WHERE LOWER("Name") = LOWER($1) AND "Section"=$2 AND "Status"<=1 LIMIT $3 OFFSET $4'
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: Is the "status" column a tinyint type?

Comment: @ShakerKamal yes

Comment: If you want to check for either the status is 0 or 1, then you should do `(Status=0 OR Status=1)`, because  `Status<=1` will also be true when the status is `-1`, or `-2`...

Comment: `States IN (0, 1)` also works.

Comment: `Status BETWEEN 0 AND 1` also works. If it's a nummeric datatype anyway. But an `IN(0,1) ` is probably the best for this.

Answer (score 1):

Your sql is okay but it will selected records if you have status like -1, -2 as @Luuk states. My recommendation to use **IN** for readability and select only status you specify

```
SELECT * FROM "Teachers" WHERE LOWER("Name") = LOWER($1) AND "Section"=$2 AND "Status" IN (0,1) LIMIT $3 OFFSET $4
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL the boolean values are usually stored in TINYINT(1) format. In your case, to retrieve the teacher where their status is either 0(false) or 1(true) the SQL query would be:

```
select * from Teachers where LOWER("Name") = LOWER($1) AND "Section" = $2 and "Status" = 0 or "Status" = 1 LIMIT $3 OFFSET $4
```

One more thing you should try to follow, try to retrieve the relevant columns from the database rather than all the columns, it is a lot more performant than getting all the columns. Assuming the Teachers table has the following columns:

- Id
- FirstName
- LastName
- FullName
- Salary
- Designation
- Status
- Section
  etc.

And, suppose you only want to get the FirstName, LastName, Designation, Section from the table. You should run the following query,

```
select FirstName,LastName,Designation,Section from Teachers where LOWER("Name") = LOWER($1) AND "Section" = $2 and "Status" = 0 or "Status" = 1 LIMIT $3 OFFSET $4
```

Hope this helps in learning SQL and best of luck!